# Access values from JSON in NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, json

I have a function that will take in a JSON object which has a similar structure as follows:-

```
{
 "listing": [
    {
        "rental_prices": {
            "shared_occupancy": "N",
            "per_week": 2308,
            "accurate": "per_month",
            "per_month": 10000
        },
        "country_code": "gb",
        "num_floors": "0",
     }
   ]
}
```

I want to be able to get all the values for `per_month` from each sub object of `listing` I can pull a specific one, i.e. using `data.listing[0].rental_prices.per_month` but I want to be able to iterate over the object and get the value and push it to a new array each time it comes aross the `per_month` key

Comment: `Array.map` would do the trick

Comment: Can you show some expected output? Can there be listing objects in the array without the per_month field?

Comment: I was thinking `Array.map` but wasn't sure. Not worked with JSON much, or JS for that matter.

@MadaManu the expected output would be a new array of the values, i.e. `[1000, 1500, 4000, 980]`

Answer (score 1):

Indeed as @mwilson suggested .map would do the trick in this case.

https://repl.it/repls/TriangularModestNormalform

```
testJson.listing.map(listing => listing.rental_prices.per_month);
```

Note: This will return an array with undefined items if per_month doesn't exist, and will also crash if renal_prices doesn't exist

Comment: That got it! Thanks!!